# How to select all options using Selectize?

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I am building a form using the jQuery selectize plugin.
Now I am trying to build a method to select all options in the selectbox and display
them as selected.

**This is the code I use:**

```
$('#select_all').click(function() {

          $('#project_user_ids option').prop('selected', true);

          $('#project_user_ids').selectize();

        });
```

It works to select all options but they are not shown in the selectbox.
I need to a way of "refreshing" the options and showing the selected options in the box.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I recently used this:

```
Selectize.prototype.selectall = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.setValue(Object.keys(self.options));
    self.focus();
};
```

And then to use it in a link:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('column-select').selectize.selectall();">
    Select All
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dynamically select all options using selectize plugin first you have to initialize plugin and get its instance.

Using the setValue() method you can change the value of the control. For example:
`selectize.setValue(['value1', 'value2']);`

Using the setValue() it is possible to set all values using simple method from underscore or lodash.
`selectize.setValue(_.keys(selectize.options));`

**Complete code should look like this**:

```
var $projectUserIds = $('#project_user_ids').selectize(); // Selectize plugin initialization
var selectize = $projectUserIds[0].selectize; // Get selectize instance

$('#select_all').click(function() {
    selectize.setValue(_.keys(selectize.options)); // Set all selectize options using setValue() method
});
```

Comment: If you do not have underscore or lodash, you can simply use `Object.keys(selectize.options))` instead of `_.keys(selectize.options)`

Answer (score 1):

I found it simpler to write a plugin that you can re-use anywhere.  Instead of overwriting the existing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> functionality, I instead set all the items using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Here is an example:

```
// plugin to set/unset all items on pressing Ctrl-Shift-A
Selectize.define('set_all', function(options) {
  var self = this;

    self.onKeyUp = (function(e) {
      var original = self.onKeyUp;

      return function(e) {
        // call original function - seems to work better calling this first
        original.apply(this, arguments);

        // keyboard event is in e.originalEvent; 'code' is the key code that was pressed
        var code = e.originalEvent.code;

        // do nothing if Ctrl-Shift-A was not selected
        if (!(e.ctrlKey == true && e.shiftKey == true && code == 'KeyA')) {
          return;
        }

        self.setValue(Object.keys(self.options));
        self.focus(); // optional - maintains focus in input
      };
    })();
});
```

Usage:

```
$('#your-input').selectize({plugins: ['set_all']});
```

The `self.focus()` call is optional, but it does keep focus in the `input` field and tends to be more intuitive.

Instead of `self.focus()` you can also change that to `self.selectAll()` to immediately select all items after adding them.  This could be useful if you want the user to immediately be able to press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and delete all the items in case they made a mistake in adding them.

You could even extend the plugin further and provide the capability to set *and* unset.  For example, this modification to the above plugin uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to set all items, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to unset all items:

```
// plugin to set/unset all items on pressing Ctrl-Shift-A / Ctrl-Shift-S
Selectize.define('set_all', function(options) {
  var self = this;

    self.onKeyUp = (function(e) {
      var original = self.onKeyUp;

      return function(e) {
        // call original function - seems to work better calling this FIRST
        original.apply(this, arguments);

        // keyboard event is in e.originalEvent; 'code' is the key code that was pressed
        var code = e.originalEvent.code;

        // do nothing if Ctrl-Shift-A/S was not selected
        if (!(e.ctrlKey == true && e.shiftKey == true && (code == 'KeyA' || code == 'KeyS'))) {
          return;
        }

        // if 'A' was pressed set and select all items; if 'S' was pressed unset all items
        if (code == 'KeyA') {
          self.setValue(Object.keys(self.options));
          self.focus();
        } else {
          self.clear();
        }
      };
    })();
});
```

Notice that I also call the original `onKeyUp` function so its functionality of filtering still works as expected.  For some reason this worked best to call *prior* to my modifications.  If I put my `setValue()/clear()` calls where the `return` statement is, the select/deselect seems to only work once.

Comment: What if using on mobile?

Comment: I don't see why mobile would act any differently - I just modified the existing plugin so however that behaves, it behaves on mobile.

Comment: I must have misunderstood then, because I thought your plugin only worked with keyboard shortcuts. Without modification this can be bound to a button click?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Jason code I changed some parts for select all listed elements (current result)

```
Selectize.define('set_all', function (options) {
            let self = this;

            self.onKeyUp = (function(e) {
                const original = self.onKeyUp;

                return function(e) {
                    original.apply(this, arguments);

                    const code = e.originalEvent.code;

                    if (!(e.ctrlKey == true && e.shiftKey == true && code == 'KeyA')) {
                        return;
                    }

                    let optionsSelected = {};

                    self.currentResults.items.forEach( (item) => {
                        optionsSelected[item.id] = self.options[item.id];
                    });

                    self.setValue(Object.keys(optionsSelected));
                };
            })();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for the "Select All" functionality, you could use a js function for `ctrl+a`.

I created this function which adds all the available options, to the active items array:

```
$('#my-select').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey == true) {
      if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97){
        var el = el=$('#my-select')[0].selectize;
        var optKeys = Object.keys(el.options);
        optKeys.forEach(function (key, index) {
          el.addItem(key);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> **try this function**

```
     function selc2SelectAll(element){
        el =  element[0].selectize;
              optKeys = Object.keys(el.options);
              optKeys.forEach(function (key, index) {
              el.addItem(key);
        });
    }

    selectZ = $('#report_emails').selectize();
    selc2SelectAll(selectZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to add a `select all` option in my dropdown

```
var selc2SelectAll = function(element) {
    var el = element[ 0 ].selectize;
    var optionKeys = Object.keys(el.options).filter(key => key !== 'all');
    el.setValue(optionKeys);
  };


  $('#report_emails').change(function() {
     selectZ = $('#report_emails').selectize();
     selc2SelectAll(selectZ);
  });
```